# UICollectionView scrolling issue - views out of order

Tags: ios, scroll, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with a custom cell calld MyCell.

I'v been struggling with the scrolling methods, My scroll is horizontal here is my code:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{

            if (velocity.x < 0)
            {
            baseOffset = MAX(0, baseOffset - offsetStep);
            baseOffset-=320;
            NSLog(@"%f", baseOffset);
            }

            else if (velocity.x > 0)
            {
            baseOffset = MIN(scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.bounds.size.width, baseOffset + offsetStep);
            baseOffset+=320;
              NSLog(@"%f", baseOffset);
        }
#if 0
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(baseOffset, 0) animated:YES];

        });
#else
        targetContentOffset->x = baseOffset;
#endif

}
```

The problems are:
 **1.** the cell is not automatically centered when scrolling
 **2.** If i reach the end of the cells and scroll again, when i scroll back it 
scrolls back to the last cell and if i scroll back again it scroll to the right cell.
**3.** same as 2 but when I'm in the first cell and scroll back.

Any help here gurus?

thanks.